# Remove text qualifier in header only

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm new to SSIS, but I've written a package that exports data from a SQL Server table to a CSV text file.  I've been asked to remove the text qualifier (double quotes) from the header only.  Can someone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how would I accomplish this?  I can't find anything on removing the qualifier from the header and keeping it for the data.

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2015 to construct the package if that helps.

Comment: I don't know of one off the top of my head, but you might be able to generate header data, write that to a file, then append the quoted data to that file. I've done similar w/ some BCP work before.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks!